# How to add spaces between bootstrap buttons without having to add margin manually?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am going through one of the online tutorial related to angular. The installed bootstrap version is 3.

The author wrote some html that goes by:

```
       <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Delete </button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Clear </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Very simple right?

Now when he displayed it on screen, the button appeared with some margins yet in my case they were placed side by side with no gaps at all.

I googled and found that I can add gap manually by multiple ways but I don't want to use any of them. I want to what is exactly missing in my case that I am not getting similar results.

I have the same version of bootstrap installed as the author and followed everything step by step. The author didn't override any default behavior anywhere.

Kindly let me know what can be the possible reason.

Thank you.

Edit:

That's how they look on my screen. No gaps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add margins to any side of an element in Bootstrap by including the `m[xytrbl]-#` class, like so:

- Margin of width level 2 all around: `m-2`
- Margin of width level 3 on the left and right sides: `mx-3`
- Margin of width level 1 on the bottom: `mb-1`
- Margin of width level 4 on the left: `ml-4`

The same idea goes for padding, replacing `m` with `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show me how it looks like at your system. I am getting these margins without any additional margins set.

[image]

Using Bootstrap 3.3.7

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Delete </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Clear </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added a pic with the question. Have a look, there is no gap. I am using Bootstrap v3.4.1.

Comment: @MuhammadFaraz: just run the snippet. There is spacing by default for bootstrap 3.x. Some other style maybe overriding it. check for `margin:0` in your css